# How to get previous stored from an an object in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm working on an application which uses `react` for the front-end and `redux` for state management.

In this application I have a `reducer`, which stores the current state of the user's presence. So whether the user is online or offline. I'm getting the current state of the user's presence using the `useSelector hook`.

My question however is how to get *previous* value stored in the `userStatus` object.

reducer.js

```
import * as actionTypes from "../actions/types";
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
const initialState = {
 
  userStatus: { value: "unavailable", label: "Offline" },
};
const user_reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    
    case actionTypes.SET_USER_STATUS:
      return {
        ...state,
        userStatus: action.payload,
      };

  
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  user: user_reducer,
 
});
export default rootReducer;
```

//getting user current presence

```
const userPresence = useSelector((state) => state.user.userStatus);
```

example:

```
current State `userStatus: { value: "unavailable", label: "Offline" }`
previous state userStatus: { value: "available", label: "Online" }
```

How can i get this previous state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating the state in redux, use `useEffect` on change of that redux state and save that state in some local state. In this case whenever redux state updates you'll have that previous state stored in local

```
function Component(props){
  const userPresence = useSelector((state) => state.user.userStatus);
const [userLocal, setUserLocal] = useState(null) 

  useEffect(()=>{
// here you have access to previous state(userLocal) and current 
// state(userPresence) 
   setUserLocal(userPresence) 
},userPresence)
}
```

Comment: Harshit Upadhyay :It will be very helpful if you can update the your answer

Comment: `const [userLocal, setUserLocal]`  :Means in `userLocal` the previous value is stored